# Is there a way to Concat multiple rows into one but keep each column value as a seperate column?

Tags: db2

I know that it is possible to almost do what I want with LISTAGG however that adds all of the values into one column.

For example if I have something like this

```
SubjectID       StudentName
----------      -------------
1               Mary
1               John
1               Sam
2               Alaina
2               Edward
```

I am hoping to get something like this

```
SubjectID       StudentName       StudentName1       StudentName2 
----------      -----------       ------------       ------------
1               Mary              John               Sam               
2               Alaina            Edward             0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called pivoting and is perfectly described in this [article](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/pivoting_tables56?lang=en_us)